# Best stats library for C (not C++)

Tags: c, statistics

Anyone know of a good statistics library for C? I'm looking for something that is commonly used and not a small project. EDIT: must be free!

Comment: To be more specific, I'm writing an option modeling library in C and I just need to be able to do simple stats calculations like a cumulative normal distribution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

gsl (http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) is widely available, portable, and has a lot of nice functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Statistics are frequently done in other languages, but some of those languages will be callable from C.  I'd recommend looking at [R](http://www.r-project.org) and [Octave](http://www.octave.org); the latter is an open source Matlab work-alike.  Both are programming languages in their own right, but many other languages can be called from C.

Answer (score -3):

In my opinion, [MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/) is a very good choice you can use for that. [Here](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_external/f38569.html) is an article on how to call MATLAB from C.

It ain't cheap. But you did not specify anything about the library being cheap or free. Plus, you are mentioning it's a big project.... :-)