# C probability library similar to R

Tags: c, r, statistics

Does anyone know a C library that has some standard probability functions like `R`s sample function? I found this:

http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/

I was wondering if anyone has had any experience with it (how efficient it is) and if there are any other ones. Thanks.

Comment: If you have a few thousand pounds spare, you can generate C code from MATLAB.  You'll need the Statistics toolbox for the sampling functions and the Coder toolbox to generate the C.

Comment: http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/classes/s243/rmath.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can always embed R itself in your C application.  That is doable, and documented, but a tad tedious as the API is pretty bare.

If you are open to C++, it gets much easier thanks to [RInside](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside.html). If you can do this in R:

```
R> set.seed(123); sample(LETTERS[1:5], 10, replace=TRUE)
 [1] "B" "D" "C" "E" "E" "A" "C" "E" "C" "C"
R>
```

you can do the same in C++ pretty easily thanks to [RInside](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside.html):

```
edd@max:~/svn/rinside/pkg/inst/examples/standard$ cat rinside_sample12.cpp
// Simple example motivated by StackOverflow question on using sample() from C
//
// Copyright (C) 2012  Dirk Eddelbuettel and Romain Francois

#include <RInside.h>                    // for the embedded R via RInside

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  RInside R(argc, argv);                // create an embedded R instance

  std::string cmd = "set.seed(123); sample(LETTERS[1:5], 10, replace=TRUE)";

  Rcpp::CharacterVector res = R.parseEval(cmd);   // parse, eval + return result 

  for (int i=0; i<res.size(); i++) {
    std::cout << res[i] << " ";
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;

  exit(0);
}

edd@max:~/svn/rinside/pkg/inst/examples/standard$
```

and given that it runs the *same code with the same RNG seed* it also returns the same result:

```
edd@max:~/svn/rinside/pkg/inst/examples/standard$ ./rinside_sample12
B D C E E A C E C C 
edd@max:~/svn/rinside/pkg/inst/examples/standard$
```

If you just drop the code I showed above into the directory `examples/standard` of an existing RInside installation and say `make`, the executable will be made and given the same basename as your source file (here `rinside_sample12` from `rinside_sample12.cpp`).

Answer (score 3):

Googling for `C statistics library`, got me some good hits with among others the GSL. See also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777503/best-stats-library-for-c-not-c) for more tips. However, I think your best option is to integrate R into your C code. You can do this in two ways:

- Call R through a system call. This is a very simple, yet effective option. Especially when there is not a great deal of data going back and forth between R and C, this works really well. Debugging R code from within Python was quite hard for example.
- Create a direct connection form within C to an R session. This works really well when there is a lot of data going back and forth between R and C because all goes through memory and not the disk. I predict however that it will be harder to write than the first solution. See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463437/r-from-c-simplest-possible-helloworld) from more information.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at meta numerics.  Its mostly a stats library.  Open source, c#.